# Odd colours in Cairo conversion to PyGame

Tags: python, pygame, cairo

When I run this:

```py
import pygame
import cairo

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 640, 480


pygame.display.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), 0, 32)

screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
ctx = cairo.Context(surface)

ctx.set_source_rgb(0, 0, 1)

ctx.rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100)
ctx.fill()
buf = surface.get_data()
img = pygame.image.frombuffer(buf, (WIDTH, HEIGHT), "ARGB")

screen.blit(img, (0, 0))

pygame.display.flip()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while not pygame.QUIT in [e.type for e in pygame.event.get()]:
    clock.tick(30)
```

the result is a window with a blue rectangle, as I would expect. However, if I change `ctx.set_source_rgb(0, 0, 1)` with `ctx.set_source_rgb(0, 0, 0)`, i.e. change the colour from `(0, 0, 1)` to `(0, 0, 0)`, I get nothing at all.

The expected behaviour would be that the rectangle is black. When I modify the blue value between 0 and 1, the opacity seems to change while the actual blue value seems to stay constant. The r and g values work as expected when b = 1. The same happens with `set_source_rgba`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem of endianness, or byte order.

Cairo's pixel formats are endian-dependent, and pygame's pixel formats are independent of endianness. See https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/2972 for more of a discussion of interoperability.

So if the bytes are flipped, and you say blue (0, 0, 1), you fill out the ARGB like [1, 0, 0, 1], because the alpha is also 1 by default. Flip [1, 0, 0, 1] and you still have the same thing.

However if you fill in ARGB for black, it goes to [1, 0, 0, 0]. Interpreting that as BGRA yields R=0, G=0, B=1, A=0. Because alpha is 0, it's completely transparent and nothing is drawn.

On a little endian system (like yours), Cairo's ARGB is equivalent to pygame's BGRA. This was just added to pygame, so you'll have to update to `pygame 2.1.3.dev8`or higher. (Right now that's the highest release of pygame, and it's a pre release, so you'd need `pip install pygame --upgrade --pre`

Then you can do `img = pygame.image.frombuffer(buf, (WIDTH, HEIGHT), "BGRA")`

Comment: I do not have much to add to this great answer, but here is a link to the relevant cairo docs. "a 32-bit quantity" refers to something like C's `uint32_t`. https://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Image-Surfaces.html#cairo-format-t